# How can I mock a laravel controller method to check if it received a call to a specific method with appropriate parameters

Tags: php, laravel, testing, controller, mockery

I am using laravel 5.4 and have a route in my api.php file like below:

`Route::middleware('auth:api')->post('/message', 'MessagesController@store');`

So initially lets just say I wanted to check that when I make a post call to 'api/message' the store() method is suppose to be called.

Below is my test code that I tried:

```
$mock = \Mockery::mock(MessagesController::class);
$mock->shouldReceive('store')->once();
$this->app->instance(MessagesController::class, $mock);

$response = $this->call('POST','api/message',[
        'receiver_id' => $receiver->id,
        'message' => 'Testing OneSignal - unit test'
    ]);
\Mockery::close();
```

When I run the test I get the following error in terminal:

`1)Tests\Feature\NotificationTest::a_onesignal_notification_is_sent_when_a_new_message_is_sent
    Mockery\Exception\InvalidCountException: Method store() from 
    Mockery_1_App_Http_Controllers_MessagesController should be called
    exactly 1 times but called 0 times.`

My intention is not really trying to check if store() method is being called, which I know I have other ways to go around. Within the store method I delegate a method to one of the traits which in returns makes a curl call, I would like to test if that method is receiving the intended paramaters.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Can you show us more code? From what you describe it seems you are violating the first principle of SOLID which is "single responsibility principle". Method `store` should store the data and do nothing else.

Comment: I am sorry if the error message confused you. As I mentioned on my original post my intention is not really checking the store method but to know how I can mock a controller and assert that a certain function is called. For conversations sake lets consider that the MessagesControlller contains a empty method named store($message) where $message is just a string. I would like to write a test where I make a POST call to /message with a message attribute. so the following should return green `$mock->shouldReceive('store')->once();` - but in my case it says that function is not being called.

Comment: Personally, I think mocking controllers is not the best way to test code. You should rather take a class you have implemented, and test it in a separated environment. This refers to UnitTesting, if you want to check your application behavior, then you can try implementing functional tests https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/application-testing I'm giving you this tip based on my experience. If you still want to persist this way, try to play with `->andReturn('test')` and inspect your responses. I suspect that Laravel is not using it's magic for controllers, and your mock is not being used.

Comment: Yes you are right that my mock is not being used at all and also on the fact that mocking controllers is not the best method. But what if I just want to check if a method is being called with appropriate parameters which happens to reside within a controller? I know that testing controllers mostly means making some assertions at database level, but in my case that method is not dealing with any database, lets say it just returns hello when "veNuker" is passed as parameter. How do I do that? I think this is definitely possible I just cant get it to work.

Comment: How about this https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/application-testing

Comment: Mate I think that link is quite far from what I was looking for, still thanks a lot for taking the time to reply.

Comment: I second the question for a similar (i think) situation : i have a front calling a Laravel API who's job is to receive front's data and pass them to an other API. I can test that Laravel's API is responding but i don't see how to test that it's sending correct value to the other API. Since i'll do a class to send data to the other API, i would like to mock this class